# Hacer un JOIN al lado de una columna en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito mostrar 3 consultas una al lado de la otra en un query usando SQL Server

1)

```sql
SELECT Datetime, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM Runtime.dbo.History
WHERE TagName IN('014AV1_002.#VOLUMH') AND DateTime > '2019-06-22 00:00:00'
AND DateTime <=  '2019-06-23 00:00:00' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
AND wwResolution = 3600000 GROUP BY DateTime
```

2)

```sql
SELECT Datetime, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM Runtime.dbo.History
WHERE TagName IN('014MP1_002.PV') AND DateTime > '2019-06-22 00:00:00' AND
DateTime <=  '2019-07-23 00:00:00' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND
wwResolution = 3600000 GROUP BY DateTime
```

3)

```sql
SELECT Datetime, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM Runtime.dbo.History
WHERE TagName IN('124EN0_001.CIUD_SUROCC.HORA ') AND DateTime > '2019-06-22 00:00:00' AND
DateTime <=  '2019-07-23 00:00:00' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND
wwResolution = 3600000 GROUP BY DateTime
```

#### Ejemplo

> | FECHA | VALOR | (Y LA OTRA AL LADO) | VALOR2 |

[image: Imagen del query]

Comment: es exactamente el mismo where?

Comment: Amigo el primer where pide los valores de '014AV1_002.#VOLUMH' y el segundo de 014MP1_002.PV

Comment: ok, comprendido.. tenes dos opciones ahora te respondo

Comment: Pefecto amigo, si podrias escribir las opciones que sugieres en el codigo mejor porque apenas estoy aprendiendo, tu disculpa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tenes dos opciones para resolver esto:

1. Joinear las dos consultas por fecha...

   ```
   select a.datetime, a.value, b.value from
   (SELECT Datetime, SUM(Value) AS Value FROM Runtime.dbo.History WHERE TagName IN('014AV1_002.#VOLUMH') AND DateTime > '2019-06-22 00:00:00' AND DateTime <= '2019-06-23 00:00:00' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND wwResolution = 3600000 GROUP BY DateTime) A inner join 
   (SELECT Datetime, SUM(Value) AS Value FROM Runtime.dbo.History WHERE TagName IN('014MP1_002.PV') AND DateTime > '2019-06-22 00:00:00' AND DateTime <= '2019-07-23 00:00:00' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND wwResolution = 3600000 GROUP BY DateTime) B on A.datetime = B.datetime
   ```
2. hacer una sola consulta y calcular los valores con un case

   ```
   SELECT Datetime, 
   SUM(case 
       when TagName = '014MP1_002.PV' then Value else 0) AS Value1,
    sum(case 
       when TagName = '014AV1_002.#VOLUMH' then Value else 0) as value2 
   FROM Runtime.dbo.History 
   WHERE TagName IN('014MP1_002.PV','014AV1_002.#VOLUMH' ) AND DateTime > '2019-06-22 00:00:00' AND DateTime <= '2019-07-23 00:00:00' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic' AND wwResolution = 3600000 
   GROUP BY DateTime
   ```

Comment: Amigo sos un crack